# Duplicate clicks on xx_Tap() happening in separate class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, methods, windows-phone-8

**The scenario:**
I want to tap on a textblock and  run a method to add that item to the cart.
No, I don't prefer buttons to textblocks, thank you :)

**The code (shoppingcart.cs)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace m_POS
{
    public class shoppingcart
    {
        int cartnum;
        int duplicate=0;
        int num_of_items;
        int counter=1;
        List<item> items = new List<item>();

        //constructor
        public shoppingcart()
        {
            this.cartnum = counter;
            counter += 1;
            this.num_of_items = 0;
            this.items = new List<item>();
            init_items();
        }

        //return the item list of tapped/purchased items
        public List<item> getitems(){
            return this.items;
        }

        //returns the number of items tapped/purchased
        public int get_num_of_items() { return this.num_of_items; }

        // the method that adds a tapped-on item to the items list
        public void additem(String itemx,String qty) {


            for (int i = 0; i < item.pick_item.Count; i++)
            {
                if (itemx.Equals(item.pick_item[i].getname()))
                {
                    item itm = new item(item.pick_item[i].getname(), 
                    item.pick_item[i].getprice());
                    itm.addqty(Convert.ToInt16(qty));
                    this.items.Add(itm);
                    Debug.WriteLine("added to cart!!");
                }
            }

                this.num_of_items += Convert.ToInt16(qty);
        }

//used to test the additem() works. Everytime the class is run, this Rolex item will
  //be the first to be added to the cart. ALWAYS. Funny thing is, it doesnt get
  // duplicated.
        private void init_items()
        {
            item itm12 = new item("Rolex", 4000);
            //additem(itm12);
            this.items.Add(itm12);
        }


    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class item
    {
        String itemname;
        int itemamount;
        int itemqty = 0;

        public static List<item> pick_item = new List<item>();

        public static List<String> menu_food = new List<string> {
        "Single Beef Burger",
           "Double Beef Burger",
           "Triple Beef Burger",
           "Single Chicken Burger",
           "Double Chicken Burger",
           "Single Veggie Burger",
           "1/2 Fries",
           "Full Fries",
           "Beef Steak",
            "Mushroom",
            "Steamed Rice",
            "Rolex"};

        public static List<String> menu_price = new List<String>{
            "8000",
            "17000",
            "25000",
            "12000",
            "26500",
            "7500",
            "4000",
            "6000",
            "20000",
            "25000",
            "17500",
            "4000"};

        public item(string name, int amount)
        {
            this.itemamount = amount;
            this.itemname = name;
            this.itemqty = 1;
        }

        public static void init_menu()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < get_menu().Count; i++)
            {
                item itm = new item(menu_food[i], Convert.ToInt32(menu_price[i]));
                pick_item.Add(itm);
            }
        }

        public void addqty(int qty) { this.itemqty = qty; }

        public string getname() { return this.itemname; }

        public int getprice() { return this.itemamount; }

        public static int getpxbyname(string itemname) {
            int ans=0;
            for (int y = 0; y < pick_item.Count; y++) {
                if (pick_item[y].itemname.ToString().Equals(itemname)) {
                    ans = pick_item[y].itemamount;
                }
            }
            return ans;
        }

        public static List<String> get_menu() { return menu_food; }

        public static List<String> get_price() { return menu_price; }


    }

}
```

**Where are the duplicates happening?**

I'm getting the additem(string itemname,int itemqty) being run **twice** on every tap. Everything else is perfect, though.

**What have I done before posting?**
- Tested the `Tap` event and made sure it was only being fired ONCE per tap? Check.

- Tested the `additem()` method to make sure it works to being with? Check. I add a single item to the cart everytime the app is started. That item never gets duplicated.

**Console Debug.WriteLine() shows**

```
added to cart!!
added to cart!!
called method with System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
```

The first two `added to cart`s are from the method being called twice.

The next `called method with System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock` is from the debug i inserted just after calling this method from the `Food.xaml.cs`

**Food.xaml.cs [part of it]**

```
    public Foods()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        item.init_menu();
        populatemenu();

    }

    public void populatemenu()
    {

        List<String> display = item.get_menu();
        for (int i = 0; i < display.Count; i++)
        {
            string tname = "tb" + i;
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Tap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(tb_Click);
            tb.Style = (Style)Resources["textblocker"];
            tb.FontSize = 36;
            tb.Text = display[i];
            tb.Name = tname;
            sp_lunch.Children.Add(tb);

        }
    }
    private void tb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tapped += 1;
        selectqty(sender);
    }

    private void selectqty(object sender) {
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.Height = 300;
        popup.Width = 400;
        popup.VerticalOffset = 100;
        PopUpControl control = new PopUpControl();
        popup.Child = control;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        string qty="";


        control.btnOK.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                popup.IsOpen = false;
                //pick input from the popup's textbox.
                qty = control.tbx.Text;
                if (qty == null||qty=="") { qty = "0"; }

                //send clicked item to cart for addition
                TextBlock clicked = ((TextBlock)sender);
                string temp = clicked.Text;
                Cart.cart_new.additem(temp, qty);
                Debug.WriteLine("called method with "+sender.ToString());
                tb_pamount_lunch.Text = Convert.ToString(Cart.cart_new.get_num_of_items());
                //tb_pamount_lunch.Text = tapped.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(temp);

                //update the dinner stackpanel to display the selected items
                sp_dinner.Children.Clear();
                List<item> display = Cart.cart_new.getitems();
                for (int i = 0; i < display.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
                    tb1.FontSize = 36;
                    tb1.Text = display[i].getname().ToString();
                    sp_dinner.Children.Add(tb1);
                }

            };
        control.btnCancel.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                //close popup when cancel is clicked
                popup.IsOpen = false;
            };
    }
```

**Any more info??**
If there's some other class you'd want to take a look at, I'll gladly copy/paste it here or upload the whole project.zip :)

Comment: i want to see the code where you are binding the tap event.

Comment: Or you call the _additem(..)_ twice (button down/up) or you called init_menu twice (so items are added twice)..  Q: Why are you store prices as string? You should use a dictionary<string, int> for your products (if you want the price stored in cents).

Comment: @NoOne i've added the method call from Food.xaml.cs :)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I hadn't known about that :o - the dictionary, i mean! Isn't btn_Tap() supposed to take care of mouse_moved_off and stuff like that, seeing as it is inbuilt?

Comment: no you haven't. i want the code where you have doe this tb.Click += tb_Click;

Comment: @NoOne I've updated - yet again :D

Comment: add e.Handled = true as the first line in your event handler

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Handled' and no extension method 'Handled' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @NoOne

Comment: it has see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx

Comment: According to [this guy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc189018%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), RoutedEvents aren't present for the Tap action. Did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you tab the thrid time, 3 items will be added.

```
(s, args) =>
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
            //pick input from the popup's textbox.
            qty = control.tbx.Text;
            if (qty == null||qty=="") { qty = "0"; }

            //send clicked item to cart for addition
            TextBlock clicked = ((TextBlock)sender);
            string temp = clicked.Text;
            Cart.cart_new.additem(temp, qty);
            Debug.WriteLine("called method with "+sender.ToString());
            tb_pamount_lunch.Text = Convert.ToString(Cart.cart_new.get_num_of_items());
            //tb_pamount_lunch.Text = tapped.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(temp);

            //update the dinner stackpanel to display the selected items
            sp_dinner.Children.Clear();
            List<item> display = Cart.cart_new.getitems();
            for (int i = 0; i < display.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
                tb1.FontSize = 36;
                tb1.Text = display[i].getname().ToString();
                sp_dinner.Children.Add(tb1);
            }

        };
    control.btnCancel.Click += (s, args) =>
        {
            //close popup when cancel is clicked
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        };
```

This is because the control still exists and every time you call *selectqty* another action is added to the eventhandler list. And will be executed more than ones. You should only register the event ones. Like in your constructor.

Personal: You should register events to a button that within a subcontrol. Instead create a new event on the control and raise it there. This will give you the advantage to change the buttons or other controls (maybee you want short-cut keys in future) on that controls without altering you mainform.

example:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        control.btnOKClicked += Control_buttonOk;
        control.btnCancelClicked += Control_buttonCancel;
    }

    private void Control_buttonOk(object sender, eventArgs e)
    {
        // implement code
    }

    private void Control_buttonCancel(object sender, eventArgs e)
    {
        // implement code
    }
}

public class UserControl1: UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnOK.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(btnOKClicked != null)
                btnOKClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        };
        btnCancel.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(btnCancelClicked!= null)
                btnCancelClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        };
    }

    public event EventHandler btnOKClicked;
    public event EventHandler btnCancelClicked;
}
```

This way you separate the functionallity/dependency of the layout of the control.

**As i was writing this, i think you might look over here:**
*Form.ShowDialog Method* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx This will handle the popup.IsOpen and will block your MainForm until it's closed. With a DialogResult you can read if the user pressed Ok or cancel.

Comment: :o you lost me back there. All the tapped items added twice, and none of them more than that.

Comment: Thanks again!! however, when i use the refactored code you've sent me, my eventhandlers in Food.xaml.cs can't pick the sender args so I get a **System.InvalidCastException** on `TextBlock clicked = ((TextBlock)sender);` which is under **private void Control_buttonOk(object sender, EventArgs e)**